# Finding a function where the limit does not exist at any real x, but a limit can exist at infinity

Tags: limits

The problem basically asks:
Find a function F such that $\lim \limits_{x \to b}F(x)$ does not exist for any real number b but $\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}F(x)$ does exist.

So the first thing that came to mind was a simple $F(x)=1$. While $\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}F(x)=1$ would be correct, so would $\lim \limits_{x \to 5}F(x)=1$ or basically $\lim \limits_{x \to b}F(x)=1$. So that's out.

Then I thought $F(x)=x$ or $F(x)=√x$ but obviously the conditions still do not apply. However I cannot just keep guessing random functions as that shows I don't have a very good understanding. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you think of a function that is bounded and, at each point, does not have a limit? (Hint: A well known example takes only two values.) Then consider the product of that function and $1/x$ (define the resulting function however you wish at $x=0).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot just keep guessing random functions as that shows I don't have a very good understanding. How should I approach this problem?

The way to approach a complicated (counter)example problem is to first think about how to solve its individual parts on their own. In this case you should consider the following sub-questions:

- How can you construct a function which is discontinuous at every real?
- What methods do you know for taking an existing function and modifying it so that it has a limit at infinity (but it isn't "too distorted")?

Re: the first point, in order to avoid giving the answer away I'm going to give an *overly complicated* example, namely [Conway's base $13$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function). This function is worth knowing on its own: not only is it discontinuous at every point, but for every nontrivial interval $(a,b)$ its range restricted to $(a,b)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Re: the second point, we can always try to "progressively scale" a given function. Specifically, given a function $f$ consider the new function $$\hat{f}: x\mapsto {f(x)\over x}.$$ The idea is that as $x\rightarrow\infty$, the denominator gets big so the whole fraction goes to zero.

... Except that that doesn't always work: sometimes $f$ just grows too fast. In particular, letting $C$ be Conway's base $13$ function it's easy to check that $\hat{C}$ does not have a limit at infinity. (Indeed, it shares with $C$ the property of having "full range" on every interval.)

This raises the following question:

> What is a sufficient property of a function $f$ to guarantee $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\hat{f}(x)}=0$?

Don't think too hard about this one:

> It's enough for $f$ to be **bounded** (above and below).

Now to get an example of the type we want, we just need to find a nowhere-continuous function with this additional nice property. There are many examples, but there's one which is probably the most common:

> The [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function): $x\mapsto 1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x\mapsto 0$ otherwise. Remember that $\mathbb{Q}$ is **dense *and* codense**: between any two reals we can find both rationals and irrationals.

---

Incidentally, I can't resist plugging my favorite analysis book here: [**Counterexamples in Analysis**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486428753). It's often hard to dive into the mindset of searching for weird stuff, and this book helps a lot. (It's a relative of an even more fun book, [**Counterexamples in Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048668735X), which while less relevant at the moment is also totally worth having. They're both Dover books too - for once the right book is *affordable*!)